# Google Chrome Extension -- Icon in browser content

Tags: browser, google-chrome, icons, google-chrome-extension

If you have seen the extension for WOT for chrome you will better understand what am trying to achieve. When we Google search we get links in return I am trying to put my extension icon after each link like WOT extension has done. And want to handle the click event on that icon. Please suggest me how I can set that icon and what calls I need to make to handle those events.

Comment: It's just pure javascript task.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to use [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) to manipulate the DOM. You want to manipulate the DOM so you can search for each search result.

After that, it is just basic JavaScript (as if you owned the Document), you can add children elements (such as your icon), and add listeners on your elements so you can click them.

Comment: I am trying to use this code but i dont know the exact class for google search results that would replace "the_search_result_class" function someFunction() 
{ 
 alert("The user clicked on the icon.") 
} 

var icon = document.createElement("img"); 
icon.src = chrome.extension.getURL("icon.png"); 
var searchResults = 
document.getElementsByClassName("the_search_result_class") 
for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) 
{ 
 var searchResultIcon = icon.cloneNode(); 
 searchResultIcon.addEventListener("click", someFunction, false); 
 searchResults[i].append(searchResultIcon); 
}